# Creation of widget that uses RSS feed, using HTML and .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, html, ajax, widget

I need to create a news widget, that takes data from a real-time RSS feed and displays them on my ajax enabled .NET website. Any Suggestions?

I was considering using an IFrame within the .NET code, and somehow call the RSS feed within it. However, from the stuff I looked up, I've learnt that you may need to embed a JavaScript within that. Wouldn't that be too complex? Surely there's an easier way than doing all this from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest http://feed.mikle.com/

FeedWind is an RSS feed widget. Simply copy & paste the snippet of code to embed into your web page. It's free and ready to use without having to register!

Comment: I don't like the use of iframe on Mikle's solution.